# How different is creating object in jQuery and pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How different is creating object in jQuery and pure JavaScript? Does jQuery use prototype pattern or constructor pattern to create an object?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery IS pure JavaScript.  So there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is simply a javascript framework and not a separate language so there is no difference.  When you're writing jQuery you're writing javascript